# CRUD and Frontend show from a custom table without shortcode

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I just wrote a plugin that creates a database, populates and edits rows from the backend, now what I need to show a list view of those rows with teir respective link to a detail viewo of each one. The shortcode approach I have already done it, but that does not get the purpose of my plugin, as I want it to be available in the Menus configuration, just like Woocommerce endpoints are. How can I do that? Has someone here done something alike?